# Git deleted one file automatically, when I swiched back to branch

Tags: git, github

I am working on branch **A** and have some changes. I had add those changes and stage them with commit command.

Then I switch to branch **b** need to see some code. Then I just switched back to again branch **A** and check the

```
git status
```

It is showing one file is deleted, but I have not deleted any file.

Why git had deleted one file automatically from **A** where I was working? Any Idea?

Comment: How are you switching branches?

Comment: @henrikhodne: git checkout B

Comment: and nothing done with B, then just switched back to A

Comment: Did you do a `git mv` or rename some file before stashing those changes in progress (and doing the 2 checkout)?

Comment: no, when I was done my changes in branch A, then I had added those and just commit locally, but not pushed. and I have not removed or deleted any file, while in the whole process.

Comment: If this is still an issue, can you show all steps and what it says when you do 'git status' between commands?